# How to extend each element of a column as a column and store it using a sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame, and I want to count the time of each `id` uses each `app_id` . As both the number of `id` and the number of `app_id` are large, I want to use `sparse.csr_matrix` to store it.

`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import random, string
def randomword(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    nums = np.arange(1000)
    appList=[]
    for i in range(length):  
        appList.append(''.join([random.choice(letters),
        str(random.choice(nums))]))
    return appList
appList= list(randomword(300000))
timeList= [random.randrange(0, 10000, 1) for _ in range(300000)]
idList= [random.randrange(0, 70000, 1) for _ in range(300000)]

df= pd.DataFrame({'id':idList, 'app_id': appList, 'time': timeList})
print(df.head())
print('idList length:',len(set(idList)))
print('appList length:',len(set(appList)))
```

`Output:`

```
      id app_id  time
0  64365   c789  7366
1  54623   a391  3080
2  58511   m570  9091
3  37657   m108  4707
4   1343   m771   973

idList length: 69062
appList length: 26000
```

`Expected:`

For convenience, I use `df.head()` as an example. The following DataFrame is what I want to get. And I expect the DataFrame to be stored as a `csr_matrix`.

```
      id   c789  a391  m570  m108  m771
0  64365   7366    0     0     0     0
1  54623      0  3080    0     0     0
2  58511      0    0   9091    0     0
3  37657      0    0     0  4707     0
4   1343      0    0     0     0   973
```

As you can see, the number of `id` is `69062` and the number of `app_id` is
`26000` , so I expect to get a `csr_matrix` with shape `(69062,26001)`.

Comment: Tested first solution in dupe and working.

Comment: Try `df.pivot_table('time','id','app_id',fill_value=0,aggfunc='first')`